# Create a delegate in an AppDomain

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, c++-cli, appdomain

How do I, using reflection, create an instance of a delegate in an application domain?

I have a C++/CLI DLL from which I dynamically load a C# DLL. Since the C# DLL is located on a network share, I load it into a separate AppDomain (where PermissionSet is PermissionState.Unrestricted).

This works fine when creating classes:

```
AppDomain^ appDomain = AppDomain::CreateDomain( ... );
Object^ obj = appDomain->CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    assemblyName,
    "MyNamespace.MyClass",
    false, // ignoreCase
    BindingFlags::CreateInstance | BindingFlags::Public | BindingFlags::Instance,
    nullptr, // binder
    args, // constructor arguments
    nullptr, // culture
    nullptr); // activationAttributes
```

However, when creating a delegate in the same way:

```
array<Object^>^ args = gcnew array<Object^>(1);
args[0] = MyFunctionThatIWantTheDelegateToWrap;
Object^ obj = appDomain->CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    assemblyName,
    "MyNamespace.MyDelegate",
    false, // ignoreCase
    BindingFlags::CreateInstance | BindingFlags::Public | BindingFlags::Instance,
    nullptr, // binder
    args, // constructor arguments
    nullptr, // culture
    nullptr); // activationAttributes
```

I get the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'MyNamespace.MyDelegate' not found.

So I assume I cannot create an instance of a delegate using `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()`. So my question is, how do I create one?

In case you wonder, here is the delegate definition:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public delegate string MyDelegate(int fieldId, int size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [AppDomain.DoCallBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback.aspx) method. Pay attention to the types used in your actual method. You might need to load other assemblies manually or set the [base direcory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase.aspx) and [private bin path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx) of the other AppDomain to be the same with your main one.